# Sending message to single person using Spring STOMP websockets

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, websocket, stomp

On the internet I've found some info on how to accept and send messages using Spring and STOMP, however I did not find any good examples on how to send a message to a single user. Only how to broadcast them to every single one. Are there any good examples on it?

I basically want to run one or two controllers with STOMP in a Spring MVC structure, so I can authenticate people outside of the websocket, and later on tie that authentication to the STOMP controllers, and for that I obviously need to be able to send messages to individuals.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a reasonable spring blog post which covers this:
http://assets.spring.io/wp/WebSocketBlogPost.html

The source code is on github (and linked from the blog).

Answer (score 2):

There is a concept of `User Destinations` where messages can be bound to a specific destination belonging to a user's session.

There is [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-user-destination) article from the `Spring docs` that explains it nicely. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the same answer with a nice code example, I've found this repo: [spring-websocket-chat](https://github.com/salmar/spring-websocket-chat)